# MySQL bit value in PHP doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have a bit type value `hasFreePackage` in database which stores `1` or `0`.

Here is my code below, This is working on my localhost and but whenever i try to upload on live server this code doesn't work.

```
public function checkBitValue($hasFreePackage)
{
   $hasFreePackage= ($hasFreePackage== 0x01)
   if($hasFreePackage==1)
       return 1;
   else
       return 0;
}
```

As live server is linux platform and i'm running windows on local. my code works on windows but not on linux So i changed my code to this code..

```
public function checkBitValue($hasFreePackage)
{
   $FreePackage= ($hasFreePackage== 0x01)
   if($FreePackage==1)
       return 1;
   elseif(ord($FreePackage==1))
       return 1;
   else
       return 0;
}
```

but still not working. I'm using yii 1.1 php framework and php versions are different.At linux is 5.2.0 and at local (windows) is 5.7

Comment: *A lot* has changed since PHP 5.2. It's over 10 years old. I'm guessing it's a version issue. And there is no PHP 5.7.

Comment: Yeah i think the same, but hosting company has that old version.

Comment: Then I recommend you consider finding a new host, there's a lot of vulnerabilities and bugs fixed since then. I personally can't take a host serious if they don't have the newer versions of PHP, or at least let you choose that yourself.

Comment: okay, i will ask them to update the version incase if they can't i will move to new hosting.

Comment: Wouldn't this one line statement enough for your function? `return ($hasFreePackage== 0x01)`.  I am not saying that this will resolve the problem that you are having. I am just saying from logical perspective.

Comment: Yeah i thought too it should work, but somehow doesn't work and it was not working on Linux @Nguaial

Comment: It is really a pain to have 2 different environments. Business implementation itself is a hell.  But having to work on 2 different environments is very unproductive.

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler:

```
{
    return $hasFreePackage ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Or, more clearly:

```
{
    return $hasFreePackage ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

The rationale:  0 is FALSE; non-zero numbers are TRUE.

Still better:  Keep that in mind and don't bother checking true/false value against true/false!

Caution:  `NULL` and `''` muddy up logic like this.  Hence the "rationale" spoke only of numbers.